# Node js - React: How to modify an API to fetch for a specific request

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing a small test program on how to use specific API from [AISHub](http://www.aishub.net/api#samples) to locate some vessel. The problem I have is that I would like to track only a specific number of vessels (total of 10 vessels) and I can't find a good way to do that. It was difficult to use those type of API and understand how to do the request. However after finally doing it I don;t know how to best look for 10 specific vessels.

Below a snippet of the working code for fetching the data and inquiring the API.

```
const btnSearch = document.getElementById('btnSearch');
const txtSearch = document.getElementById('boat');
const resultArea = document.getElementById('result');
let out = '';

const fetchConfig = {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'cors'
};

btnSearch.onclick = function() {
    var searchTerm = txtSearch.value;
    const url = 'http://data.aishub.net/ws.php?username=My_KEY&format=1&output=json&compress=1';
    console.log(url);
    fetch(url, fetchConfig)
        .then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            return data.json();
        })
        .then(function(jsonObject) {
            console.log('Read This??????');
            console.log(jsonObject);
            for (boat in jsonObject) {
                const boatInfo = [
                    jsonObject[boat].mmsi,
                    jsonObject[boat].time,
                    jsonObject[boat].longitude,
                    jsonObject[boat].latitude,
                    jsonObject[boat].cog,
                    jsonObject[boat].sog,
                    jsonObject[boat].heading,
                    jsonObject[boat].navsat,
                    jsonObject[boat].imo,
                    jsonObject[boat].name,
                    jsonObject[boat].callsign,
                    jsonObject[boat].type,
                    jsonObject[boat].a,
                    jsonObject[boat].b,
                    jsonObject[boat].c,
                    jsonObject[boat].d,
                    jsonObject[boat].draught,
                    jsonObject[boat].dest,
                    jsonObject[boat].eta
                ];
                boatOut(boatInfo);
                console.log(boatInfo);
            }
            resultArea.innerHTML = out;
        })
        .catch(function(e) {
            console.log('Error' + e);
        });
};

function boatOut(boat) {
    console.log(boat);
    out += `<div class="boat">
            <div class="boatText">
            <h2>${boat[0]}</h2>
            <h3>${boat[0]}</h3>
            <p><em>${boat[0]}</em></p>
            </div><!-- boatText -->
            </div><!-- boat -->`;
}
```

**What I have done so far:**

1) On the [official documentation](http://www.aishub.net/api#samples) there is a limited type of examples on how to use them. I tried to play a little bit with the operations they procedure they provide but could not find a way to only inquire for 10 vessels.

2) It was useful the [sample part](http://www.aishub.net/api#samples) as it explained how the data are formatted and how to structure the proper answer. And that how I exactly parsed the file in the request. Although it only return all data or a specific interval .

3) I was looking a [this spurce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to see if there is something I should do to organize the API provided by AISHub and ask for only a limited number of vessels altogether but no success so far.

I am not sure on how to move on and inquired the API for only 10 vessels. Thanks for pointing in the right direction on how to solve this problem.

Comment: There might not be a way. It seems to be a very limited API. They would have to build that in along with the logic for how it determines which 10 to result (i.e. the sorting logic). If it does exist, it could have *any* parameter format, so there's no way for us to know. The best bet you have is to write them and ask, or fetch what it gives you and reduce it to 10 yourself.

Comment: @tmdesigned, thanks for reading my question. I will try both options and hopefully when I call them they could be more specific.